# ERROR Installing Rails: activesupport requires Ruby version >= 2.7.0. (Looking for solution)

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am getting started with my tech journey. I'm looking to install Ruby. I'm stuck at the moment, I do need help please. When I try to install this is what it is showing me

$ gem install rails
ERROR: Error installing rails:
activesupport requires Ruby version >= 2.7.0.

I checked my rails version is Rails 5.1.3. Please how do I solve this problem? Looking forward to replies, thanks.

Comment: Did you get any solution to this? I'm also stuck at a moment with same problem.

Answer (score 0):

Check your ruby version `ruby -v`. It is lower than required, so you should install newer version.

Comment: Okay, thanks for the reply. Should I uninstall the current version I have before installing the new one? Or should I just go ahead and install the newer version?

Comment: I don't know how do you install Ruby, here is a post with explanation o 3 ways of installing Ruby: https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-install-ruby-on-ubuntu-18-04/  (I use rvm, rbenv is also ok, they both give you a possibility of installing and using many Ruby versions, which is very useful and convenient).